# Cross-platform ORM for C# that's free and not NHibernate?

Tags: asp.net, database, orm, mono

I've got a client who wants an ASP.NET MVC application.  I'll develop it with VS.NET 2010 Express, demo it to him on my Linux server during its development (Mono supports ASP.NET MVC), and he'll eventually host it on a commercial provider running IIS.

Getting this done quickly is the name of the game.  The only piece I'm missing here is the database layer.  Ideally I'd use SQL CE and EF4.  But SQL CE only works on Windows, and Mono doesn't support the Entity Framework anyway.

The only free Linq to SQL-like option I see is DbLinq. A quick test with that on a MySQL database had it erroring out on a table that had two foreign keys to a single primary key. A search on Google shows that this bug was identified, and a patch was created, two years ago or so.  That the patch still hasn't been applied to the main source by now, and that this bug seems to affect so a common scenario, does not fill me with confidence on the production-readiness of DbLinq.

Even if it did work, it'd have to be with MySQL, as that's the only database I can expect to be available on both Linux and an eventual Windows server.  (SQLite, Berkeley DB, etc., would all require some native drivers be installed on the server, which I can't count on.)

I don't know NHibernate.  But from what I read, it requires manually creating XML mapping files... so I don't have to write SQL statements, but I do have to create mapping files?  (Plus I'd need to learn how to use it.)  Like I said above: Getting this done quickly is a goal here.

If I must, I will just pony up the $5 a month or so for a cheap ASP.NET hosting provider and use that to demo progress to the client, using SQL CE and EF4.  But before I do that I'd just like to see if there are any other viable options.  (It's kind of mostly an intellectual exercise by this point.)

So... any tips?

Comment: Why are you so - sorry - unprofessional not to be able to how an ASP.NET MVC application on a Windows Server? They come prety miuch for free with MSDN (as well as a serious version of VS) and as a consultant having clients you should have a - i dont know - ah - professional infrastructure.

Comment: The last part of my post says that if need be I'll pay for a hosted provider and "it's kind of mostly an intellectual exercise by this point."  I hope that negates your view of me as unprofessional.

Comment: Also: I'm not a consultant, I'm a 9-to-5'er doing this for a friend and don't want to pay for a "serious version of VS" for this one project.  Even if I did, it wouldn't solve my problem, which is not having my own Windows server to host this on and being unable to find a good data layer that works with Mono.  If you have solutions to that problem (but not recommendations to do it some other way) I'd be pleased to entertain them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You COULD try Linq-to-SQL. Partially supported under Mono from 2.6, it supports many dbs under mono [Release Notes Mono 2.6](http://www.mono-project.com/Release_Notes_Mono_2.6#LINQ_to_SQL) (they are working with those of DbLINQ to make it).

Ah... Forget to learn quickly how to use nhibernate. It's very good but it's quite an hell. And creating the XML is the least (and with NHibernate 3.2 they have added their version of Fluent interfaces, so XML aren't anymore necessary I think. You can "code" your XML.)

Comment: I was under the impression that Mono's linq-to-sql code was co-opted from DbLinq, meaning it'd have the same questionable produciton-readiness mentioned above.  But I see by the link you provided that they don't actually say that, just that they're working with the DbLinq team.  I'll give it a try and report back what I discover!

Comment: I did went up using linq 2 sql (DbLinq).  Even though it seems to have problems (like what I mentioned in the original post) and several methods are still unimplemented, and I have to manually edit the DBML file if I want my tinyint(1) columns to be accessible as booleans instead of sbytes, I've decided to work around those problems.

Answer (score 2):

Does it really have to be a fully bloated ORM?

I recommend to have a look at some of the so called "micro-orm`s", especially my favourite one: Peta-Poco (http://www.toptensoftware.com/petapoco/)

Peta-Poco runs perfectly under mono and has an incredible performance. Even better, because of the small codesize (~1k lines of c#) it is very easy to understand what`s going on under the hood and you can easily change/extend the code to your needs. For the start you just have to copy the single .cs file in your project and you are ready to go.

Peta-Poco has a very well poco-mapping heuristic so you will get your c# objects out of the db with zero configuration for the most cases.